# Access bash tab completions from script

Tags: bash, autocomplete, tab-completion, compgen

You normally interact with bash completion by pressing the `tab` key in your terminal. I would like to interact with it within a script of mine. Essentially, I would like a function/command that answers the question "If I pressed `tab` with text xyz already typed and the cursor as position n, what would be the suggestions?"

Does this function exist? I found `compgen` but it's poorly documented and doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The `compgen` seems to be exactly what you'd like to use anyway. To display what would happen if you'd be typing `com` and hitting the TAB key, use:

```
compgen -c com
```

Or:

```
compgen -A command com
```

This will output all Bash builtins along with external binaries and scripts found from the `PATH`.

More information can be found from [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) in case you'd like to, for example, prune out from the output of `compgen` all Bash builtins and display just the external binaries/scripts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. If I type `git sta<tab>` I get 3 suggestions: `stage`, `stash`, and `status`. But if I run `compgen -c 'git sta'` I get no suggestions.

Comment: Well, it isn't the Bash completion doing the completion for git subcommands, so it'll never work as you'd like it to work. However, compgen *does* produce for you what Bash would produce.

Comment: Well, that wasn't very clear of me. It's Bash, but it's not *vanilla* Bash doing the completion. You don't state the system you're running Bash in, but assuming it's a GNU/Linux distribution of a kind, you'll probably find `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` (or something named similarly) which either contains the magic itself or sources the magic, from say `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`. The paths mentioned in this comment are from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; so, your distribution might use different filenames but the mechanism is still the same.

Comment: So it's rather system dependent then. I want to mimic bash's tab completion, but I don't really want to re-implement all of bash's logic for looking up and loading/sourcing/whatever these files. Is there a way I can do that? Maybe some flag or input I can give to `bash` itself, like `bash -c "git s\t"` or something?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you want to mimic *vanilla* Bash, then your best bet is what's mentioned above ie. `compgen`. If you want to mimic what's going on in the particular system you're using -- where git subcommands get completed too -- you'd have to implement all the magic on top of compgen yourself. At this point it might be a good idea to settle with `compgen`, as anything more is not likely to justify the trouble of implementation.

Comment: I have exactly the same question as OP. But I'm not sure I understand the conclusion. @SamiLaine are you saying that it is *impossible* to find out what the completion of a given string (f.ex. "ssh webser") would be by using the `compgen` and `complete`?